# Find probability distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF: $f_X(x)=ce^{-|x|}, c \in \Bbb R$.
>
> Find $c$ and $F_X(x)$

My attempt:

We know that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x)=1 \implies ... \implies c=1/2$

To find $F$:

if $x<0,\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^tdt=...=\frac{1}{2}e^x$,

if $x \ge 0,\int_{0}^{x}f_X(t)dt=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}-e^{-t}dt=...=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-x})$

But the part for $x \ge 0$ can't be correct because $\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-x})$ is $0$ when $x=0$.

But $-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}-e^{-t}dt$ is indeed equal to $\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-x})$, confirmed from WolframAlpha.

So the error must be the fact that I'm using the wrong integral to find $F$.

But I don't if I'm doing anything wrong or where I'm doing it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to add to $F_X(x)$ the contribution of the integral from $-\infty$ to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in calculating the $F_X(x)$ when $x>0$:

if $x>0, F_X(x)=\frac12+\int_0^\infty f_X(t)dt.$

This is because $F_X(0)=\frac12$, not $0$.

Comment: Yes, this was obvious. Somehow I thought I did that